# How can I obtain golden naxxramus cards?

Tags: hearthstone

I was watching Hosty play recently and noticed that all of his cards are gold - I was not aware I could obtain golden Naxx cards. What do I have to do to get golden naxx cards?

Are they simply craftable or do I also have to beat the Heroic bosses?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gold Naxxaramas cards are all crafted.

They are not obtained by beating the bosses on heroic. You can craft them after you get the normal versions of the card by beating Naxxaramas.

[Source](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Curse_of_Naxxramas)

> Golden versions of cards are not obtainable through play, but become craftable using Arcane Dust once the player has obtained the regular version of that card. Golden Curse of Naxxramas cards cost the usual amount to craft for their rarity.

Comment: I believe you, but is there a source you can add to this response?

Comment: Consider it done!

Comment: I typically consider golden Nax cards a sign that someone has WAY too much dust (time) on their hands!

Comment: Or does not want to save up the gold to complete Nax and would rather collect dust to build the cards he needs, but that would take WAY too much time.

Comment: @ShadowZ. you need to acquire them through the campaign first anyway

Comment: Is that so? Interesting, guess my friend was wrong.